# Intercept SQL Query Data between Client and Server to test encryption

Tags: sql-server, networking, encryption, wireshark

Morning all,

This is my first stab at this so I'm happy to admit I'm certainly lacking in some knowledge here but I am here because I'm struggling to find answers online.

I want to double-check whether or not data being transferred from SQL Server to a client application (in this case Excel) is encrypted or not. Now, ideally I'd like to see the data from the request as either plain text (un-encrypted) or a bunch of meaningless characters (encrypted) - of course that's a massive simplification.

I have tried installed WireShark and Microsoft Message Analyzer and run traces on port 1433 when I've connected to SQL Server and then (in Excel) connected and downloaded data...I can get the SQL Query that is being run (ie: Select * from MyTable) but I can't seem to get any of the actual data from the table (e.g: results from the above query as you'd see in SSMS).

Now, I'm sure there are other ways to ensure the traffic is encrypted but I wanted to start with actually capturing the data in transit and looking at it and then trying with ODBC encryption on and/or SSL enabled on my SQL Server box.

I keep finding articles on looking at the SQL Query but the actual goal is to try and see if the data being transmitted can be viewed.

Hopefully this makes sense?

Cheers,
Ben

Answer (score 0):

There is ample documentation how to set this up. Read [Enable Encrypted Connections to the Database Engine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/enable-encrypted-connections-to-the-database-engine), [Encrypting Connections to SQL Server](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189067(v=sql.105).aspx), [How to enable SSL encryption for an instance of SQL Server by using Microsoft Management Console](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/316898/how-to-enable-ssl-encryption-for-an-instance-of-sql-server-by-using-microsoft-management-console) and I'm sure there are many more.

Furthermore, the SQL Server DMV [`sys.dm_exec_connections`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-exec-connections-transact-sql) has a column that clearly indicates whether a connections is encrypted or not:

> `encrypt_option`  `nvarchar(40)`  Boolean value to describe whether encryption is enabled for this connection. Is not nullable.

If you really want to look at the wire frames (which is kind of useless given the information in the DMV), then the [Microsoft Message Analyzer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj714801.aspx) has a [TDS protocol](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd304523.aspx) parser, and there are also TDS parsers for other wire inspection products. Such parsers can show details of the transport, including encryption flags etc. But one must be aware that SQL Server will by default use [Shared Memory](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187892(v=sql.105).aspx) transport for local connections, so when testing connections to `localhost` most likely you won't hit the TCP stack and your wire inspectors will fail to see *any* traffic.

Comment: Hi Remus, Thank you for the prompt reply - I hear you on the localhost issue - I have found that problem so I've used another machine that has SQL installed on it and I've found that to work nicely. 

I've gone through those pages but in a sense I've got 2 options: apply SSL to SQL Server or use the ODBC encryption options (if available for the correct drivers). I am just very curious to see it in action. I've applied to extra columns in MMA for SQLBatchPacketData.* but I only get some SQL Queries but no data...I feel like I'm missing something critical here...1 piece of the jigsaw

Comment: 1) ODBC cannot encrypt more than SQL Server can. ODBC can only expose SQL Server capabilities. 2) you can force the desired transport locally by prefixing the server name with `tcp:` or `np:` (for named pipes).

Comment: Ok, but I'm still stuck...I cannot find my query results when i connect from my local machine to a remote SQL Server instance and bring across a table...Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0):

If you use a database proxy (like [Gallium Data](https://www.galliumdata.com)), you should be able to see all the traffic, and even modify that traffic. It handles encryption so that shouldn't be an obstacle.